# always open sidebar with Onsen ui

Tags: onsen-ui

I'm trying to have an always open sidebar on desktop and screens that are large enough. and the a sidebar on mobile;

like the one shown here: http://onsen.io/pattern-sliding_menu.html
but there when you click on the main page the sidebar goes away.

any way to make it stick? I couldn't find anything for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onsen UI has `<ons-split-view>` for that. Explained in the docs: http://onsen.io/reference/ons-split-view.html

```
<ons-split-view
  secondary-page="secondary.html"
  main-page="main.html"
  main-page-width="70%"
  collapse="portrait">
</ons-split-view>
```